# Browser display of host filesystem

Tags: javascript, html, directory

I am working on an embedded project that implements a filesystem on a flash card.  An embedded web server provides user interface and control through a web browser.  One of the required functions is the ability to upload/download files to/from the embedded filesystem and the local (browser) filesystem.  The upload function will be easy - using an HTML input type of "file" I can create a file selection box in the browser that displays a popup window and allows browse/selection of the local filesystem file to upload.  The extension of the file will tell me where to put it in the embedded filesystem.  The problem I'm facing is download - HTML5 provides a download attribute that pops up a window that shows me where to store it on the local filesystem.  My problem is how to display the remote embedded filesystem directory so I can select which file to download.  I can provide any information needed about that directory via the embedded web server, I just don't know how to (easily) create a nice browser popup window that will allow me to display/browse the remote filesystem.  Is there any browser popup window that functions for the host side like there is for the client side?

Comment: The short answer is: you'll have to write your own. You can't tell the browser to download a file to a remote filesystem. Your server would have to handle that.

Comment: I understand that the server will have to handle the information to be displayed in the browser.  The question is how to display it in the browser.

Comment: Send it down from the server and compile that data into some HTML and CSS that suits your tastes.